# How can I remove self-closing source tags when rendering HTML markup?

Tags: 7, nodes

I use this markup in a node body.

```html
<video>
  <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  my title
</video>
```

The following markup is instead rendered in the node view.

```html
<video>
  <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    my title
  </source>
</video>
```

`</ source>` is added to the markup, and renders the full HTML not valid.

How can I avoid `</ source>` is added?

Comment: Hi. This depends on how your html-filters are configured. Do you use a wysiwyg plugin? Actually your code should work, I just tried on a D7 site (Full HTML with CK-Editor) and it worked.

Comment: Hi,this problem always. drupal add "/source" closed to my code, after rendering, html code not valid in w3validator.  for example: I install new drupal without any module, but I have problem by closing tags. drupal automaticly close source tag.

Comment: Are you using the CKEditor wysiwyg?

Comment: No, this from drupal core. drupal core close all tags in html render, and source tag close automaticly and in html source w3validator this is have error.

Comment: Drupal doesn't do tag correcting if you are not using filters or WYSIWYG. My guess is your browser could be doing it. In either case, source _has_ no closing tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use this code for replace < /source> in theme

```
  $content_this =  render($content['body']);
  print str_replace("</source>","",$content_this);
```

in node.tpl.php

Comment: Don't do this, just remove the closing tag />: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source

Comment: Also certainly don't put logic or processing logic in template files.

Comment: drupal 7 by zero settings, add < /source>  tag automaticly... I am not using filters or WYSIWYG. < /source>  must remove on html source

Comment: You didn't read what I wrote. Just remove the /> on the source tag you entered.

Comment: remove /> not working.